# PROTOCOL BUFFER ERROR due to incompatible versions

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, protoc

I am trying to compile on ubuntu 18.04 and receive the following error -
`file.pb.h:17:2: error: #error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is`

`protoc --version
libprotoc 3.6.1`

from `google/protobuf/stubs/common.h`

`#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERSION 3006001`

So looks like the versions match. 
I did do a remove of any older versions just in case using the following link
https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/protobuf-compiler?action=remove

What am I missing here ?

Comment: You need to recompile `file.proto`, which will produce fresh copies of `file.pb.h` and `file.pb.cc`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Got it to compile. Thanks